# Copying tag wiki from a sister site

Tags: discussion

Is it allowed (okay) to copy a tag's wiki from another SE site to our site ? Adapting it, and of course citing the SE source.  Same exact tag on both sites but no wiki on DSP SE while it's fully described on the sister site.